# Structuring data in Firebase for multiple hashtags during parse to Firebase migration

Tags: parse-platform, firebase, database-migration, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Data is structured as JSON. As per the best practice we should create denormalised form of Data. We should push same data in different nodes. As per their documentation it is okay to duplicate data in different branch.

**How should I structure this data in Firebase?**

I am writing a blogging application that was there in PARSE and wants to migrate to Firebase .

Each of my Blog is having different hashTags. These HashTags are clickable. So when we click a particular hashTag it will redirect to a page with common blogs having same hashTags .

How do we conceptualize above hash tag behaviour in Firebase.
How to structure the data so that i can query all blogs for a particular hashtag ?

like `select * from [blogs] where tag = '#hashtag'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
blogs
  blog_01
    hashtag:"#hashtag"
    data: "some data"
  blog_02
    hashtag: "#anotherHashtag"
    data: "more data"
  blog_03
    hashtag: "#superHashtag"
    data: "another data"
```

and the code

```
ref = rootRef.childByAppendingPath("blogs")
ref.queryOrderedByChild("hashtag").queryEqualToValue("#anotherHashtag")
            .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        //.Value can return multiple nodes within the snapshot so iterate over them
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let hash = child.value.objectForKey("data") as! String
            print(hash) //prints 'more data'
        }  

})
```

Edit: This is OS X Swift code but you can get the general idea as it applies across platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I think Firebase wants you to do something similar to this:

```
{
  "blogs": {
    "blog1": {
      "name": "blogpost1",
      "text": "blogpost1 text"
      "tags": {
        "tag1": true,
        "tag2": true,
        "tag3": true
      }
    },
    "blog2": {
      "name": "blogpost2",
      "text": "blogpost2 text"
      "tags": {
        "tag1": true
      }
   },
   "blog3": {
     "name": "blogpost3",
     "text": "blogpost3 text"
     "tags": {
        "tag1": true
      }
   }
}

{
  "tags": {
    "tag1": {
      "blog1": true,
      "blog2":true,
      "blog3":true,
    },
    "tag2": {
      "blog1":true
    },
    "tag3": {
      "blog1":true
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.  Essentially you would query your tags json with the each tag containing the key for a respective blog post.  A good next step would be to probably, as opposed to putting true as a value in the tags, put a date so that you can order the post in your search results sequentially.

Post what you came up with as a solution please.

Comment: What you have showed above is correct. But lets suppose you are trying to get all blogs for tag1 . Then i will first find all blogs related to tag1. And again for each blog i call one more web service to get the details .So to show a page we are calling firebase 4 times . Is it expected behavior.  Currently i am doing as you have shown .

Comment: In a 1 word answer 'yes'.

[link](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html)

That is the link to the official documentation.  The section is joining flattened data.

"Is it really okay to look up each record individually? Yes......"

Comment: If you are concerned about performance you may want to possibly look at implementing a device side cache as well.